# How can I set "tel:" links to open Google Voice in Brave?

Tags: facetime, web-browser, call, google-voice

I want to be able to click `tel:` links and have them open https://voice.google.com/u/0/calls?a=nc.

Here is what I have tried (based on [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1501878/is-there-a-way-to-set-google-voice-as-default-tel-protocol-handler#comment2721728_1625038)):

1. Open a tab to https://voice.google.com/u/0/messages
2. Then open the dev tools and run this in the console: `window.navigator.registerProtocolHandler("tel", "https://voice.google.com/u/0/calls?a=nc,%s","phone");`
3. Accept the prompt
4. Visit brave://settings/handlers?search=protocol+handlers and confirm that it shows that tel: is handled by voice.google.com.
5. Open FaceTime
6. Log in to FaceTime
7. In FaceTime > Settings, confirm that "Default for calls" is already set to "Brave Browser.app"

[image: Brave settings]

However, currently when I click a "tel:" link, it opens a new tab in Brave that just says "about:blank".